# How to control the jump of my RigidbodyFPSController?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to control the jump of my RigidBodyFPSController ( a Unity5 script) for a survival game.
The problem is that:
I don't know where is the  isJumping variable (forExample, type bool) which allow my character can jump. I want to manipulate that variable to change it to false when my character have low stamina.
What is the way to do that?

```js
var size : Vector2 = new Vector2(240, 40);

//Health Variables
var healthPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 20);
var healthBarDisplay : float = 1;
var healthBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var healthBarFull : Texture2D;

//Hunger Variables
var hungerPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 60);
var hungerBarDisplay : float = 1;
var hungerBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var hungerBarFull : Texture2D;

//Thirst Variables
var thirstPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 100);
var thirstBarDisplay : float = 1;
var thirstBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var thirstBarFull : Texture2D;

//Stamina Variables
var staminaPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 140);
var staminaBarDisplay : float = 1;
var staminaBarEmpty : Texture2D;
var staminaBarFull : Texture2D;

//Fall Rate
var healthFallRate : int = 150;
var hungerFallRate : int = 150;
var thirstFallRate : int = 100;
var staminaFallRate : int = 35;

private var chMotor : CharacterMotor;
private var controller : CharacterController;

var canJump : boolean = false;

var jumpTimer : float = 0.7;

function Start()
{
    chMotor = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
    controller = GetComponent(CharacterController);
}

function OnGUI()
{
    //Health GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (healthPos.x, healthPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), healthBarEmpty);
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * healthBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), healthBarFull);
    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    //Hunger GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (hungerPos.x, hungerPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), hungerBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * hungerBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), hungerBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    //Thirst GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (thirstPos.x, thirstPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), thirstBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * thirstBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), thirstBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();

    //Stamina GUI
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (staminaPos.x, staminaPos.y, size.x, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), staminaBarEmpty);

    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * staminaBarDisplay, size.y));
    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), staminaBarFull);

    GUI.EndGroup();
    GUI.EndGroup();
}

function Update()
{
    //HEALTH CONTROL SECTION
    if(hungerBarDisplay <= 0 && (thirstBarDisplay <= 0))
    {
        healthBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / healthFallRate * 2;
    }

    else
    {
        if(hungerBarDisplay <= 0 || thirstBarDisplay <= 0)
        {
            healthBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / healthFallRate;
        }
    }

    if(healthBarDisplay <= 0)
    {
        CharacterDeath();
    }

    //HUNGER CONTROL SECTION
    if(hungerBarDisplay >= 0)
    {
        hungerBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / hungerFallRate;
    }

    if(hungerBarDisplay <= 0)
    {
        hungerBarDisplay = 0;
    }

    if(hungerBarDisplay >= 1)
    {
        hungerBarDisplay = 1;
    }

    //THIRST CONTROL SECTION
    if(thirstBarDisplay >= 0)
    {
        thirstBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / thirstFallRate;
    }

    if(thirstBarDisplay <= 0)
    {
        thirstBarDisplay = 0;
    }

    if(thirstBarDisplay >= 1)
    {
        thirstBarDisplay = 1;
    }

    //STAMINA CONTROL SECTION
    if(controller.velocity.magnitude > 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 10;
        chMotor.movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = 10;
        staminaBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / staminaFallRate;
    }

    else
    {
        chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 6;
        chMotor.movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = 6;
        staminaBarDisplay += Time.deltaTime / staminaFallRate;
    }

    //JUMPING SECTION
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump == true)
    {
        staminaBarDisplay -= 0.2;
        Wait();
    }

    if(canJump == false)
    {
        jumpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = false;
    }

    if(jumpTimer <= 0)
    {
        canJump = true;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = true;
        jumpTimer = 0.7;
    }

    //if(staminaBarDisplay <= 0.05)
    //{
        //canJump = false;
        //chMotor.jumping.enabled = false;
    //}

    //else
    //{
        //canJump = true;
        //chMotor.jumping.enabled = true;
    //}

    if(staminaBarDisplay >= 1)
    {
        staminaBarDisplay = 1;
    }

    if(staminaBarDisplay <= 0)
    {
        staminaBarDisplay = 0;
        canJump = false;
        chMotor.jumping.enabled = false;
        chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 6;
        chMotor.movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = 6;
    }
}

function CharacterDeath()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("SIMPLELEVEL");
}
function Wait()
{
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.1);
    canJump = false;
}
```

Here is the code. I don't know how to control the features of the class CharacterMotor, because i think that class was replaced by RygidbodyFirstPersonController.

Comment: Your question is vague, provide some code. What ahve you tried?
Without seeing your code i would assume you want a `isGrounded` bool that tells if the player is touching the ground or not.

Comment: here is the code that I try to understand. That code use a class calles Character Motor which is obsolete in unity.

Comment: im kinda confused. your bool var is there `canJump` exists.
and your stamina sets `canJump = false;` if `stamina <= 0`. you have what you want, whats the problem?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I was confused too, but I 've investigated and found the answer. I can use all variables of RygidbodyFirstPersonController which it is in my character. I created an object type RygidbodyFirstPersonController and the rest of the way was easy :). I had to use that code to create an object of that type. The code:using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard controller there is no isJumping variable, but what you can do is set JumpForce = 0 instead for the same effect.

Or you can easily add code for this, in RigidbodyFirstPersonController.cs add some bool value isJumping, and then in Update function make sure to set m_Jump = true only if isJumping is true.

Answer (score -2):

There is a section named JUMPING SECTION. That code controls the jump function. If you want to make some changes, just change this section.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wanted. He is aware of that section. Anyway, he has already accepted another answer, and in the comments he says he has found the solution.